# What would you call a line of code stored as a variable

Tags: python

if i have a line of code stored as a variable would it be called a string

eg.

```
with open(filename) as Class:
```

would class be a string or something else?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Are you asking whether all variables are strings?

Comment: A line of code as a string is called a Security hole :)

Comment: The accept on the posted answer must mean that you just wanted to know what `Class` would be there. Did you try doing anything with `Class` on the next line? Anything at all?

Comment: no but it was answerd in a comment and the other person took his time to make a answer for me so it put it as accepted to give him the rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the

```
with X as Y
```

construct is for **Context Managers**, and `Y` is just a **variable name, consisting of context manager constructed by X**. There are no strings involved here. This is not "line of code stored as variable", this is an object created by X stored in Y, creating a context, which will at the very end of this code block call an `__exit__` method to free resources (such as close a file).

For more detailed explanation see the original [PEP document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

In particular it would not work with strings

```
with "test" as var:
    print var
```

results in an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
```

because string **it not a context manager**.

`open` on the other hand returns the instance of `file` type which is a context manager

```
print open('somefile.txt')
```

gives you

```
<open file 'somefile.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7fdec7469db0>
```

and if you dir its methods

```
print dir(open('somefile.txt'))
```

you get

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines', 'xreadlines']
```

which in particular include `__enter__` and `__exit__` which are context managers elements